# Adding an Array to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on an API and its post method expects the message value as an array. How could i add it?

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var url = "http://apidomain.com/api_post.asp";
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    string[] myMessage = new string[] { "my test string" };
    data["type"] = "1";
    data["u"] = "username";
    data["p"] = "password";
    data["message"] = myMessage;
    data["title"] = "myTitle";

    var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
    string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

    Console.WriteLine(responseInString);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I am getting the following exception when I compile

> Cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string

Comment: You're probably going to have to figure out how the message is being serialized (aka, how it's translated to a nice single string.)  For instance, a service might serialize to XML, or to JSON, and expect the message in that format.  Then the value is deserialized back into an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Add Newtonsoft.Json from Nuget in your project and then use following-

```
data["message"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myMessage);
```

It will serialize your value into string and this is how it will look like-

> ["my test string"]

Comment: no compile error. server is still responding like "expecting an array for message."

Comment: Because we are now sending the message as an array, are you sure no other field is expected as array by endpoint?

Comment: sadly yes. there is sample php curl request below: 
$data = array(
 'type' =>'1',  
 'u' =>'username',
 'p' =>'password',
 'message'=>["message1"],
 'title'=>'test',
 'numbers'=>'no1,no2,no3'
 ); 
cURL($url,$data);

Comment: i have noticed that data["message"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myMessage); is still sending string because data["message"] has declared as a string. how can i declare an array to a NameValueObject?